# Capturing output of an expect session with a bash script

Tags: bash, expect

I have a bash script that is using xmlstarlet to manipulate some key/value pairs in an application configuration file to prepare the file to be moved to a new production host.  The values that need changed are host/encryption specific.

In order to discover one of the new values I need to interact with a vendor provided script in an expect session and capture the output into a variable in the bash script so I can continue to use it.

The expect part of the bash script looks something like this:

```
expect <<DONE
    spawn command_provided_by_vendor
    expect :
    send -- "newvalue\r"
DONE
```

This is where I get stuck

In a shell the output of this command looks like:

```
Encrypted value (case sensitive, please cut and paste): 2qIrRvcSoHMb55dpcef6vw==
```

What I need to do is capture the non-whitespace output after the ":" and nothing I've tried works due to regexp errors, the parenthesis in the prompt string, etc.

There are other questions on stackoverflow that are similar, but I failed to understand how those answers helped my problem.

Any help, pointers appreciated.

Comment: In what way do you get stuck?

Comment: I was failing at what glenn posted below, getting expect to capture the output correctly.  my regexes were failing but Glenn showed me how to completely avoid that part of my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the expect command to look for an appropriate regular expression and capture the value there:

```
value=$(
    expect <<DONE
        spawn command_provided_by_vendor
        expect :
        send -- "newvalue\r"
        expect -re {Encrypted value.*: (\S+)}
        puts $expect_out(1,string)
        expect eof
DONE
)
```

Comment: If I've made a mistake, use `expect -d <<DONE` to enable debugging -- that will reveal how the pattern is/isn't matching.

Comment: I got the expect part of this working, and it appears to be behaving correctly.  I have a secondary issue where the $() is capturing all output from expect instead of just the regex match.  Would a bash function be better?

Comment: In expect, add the command `log_user 0` and use `spawn -noecho`. That should leave `puts` as the only output